# How many "marvelous" points inside a triangle.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

We call a point $P$ inside a triangle $\triangle ABC$ marvellous if exactly $27$ rays can be drawn from it, intersecting the sides of $\triangle ABC$ such that the triangle is divided into $27$ smaller triangles of equal areas.

Determine with proof the total number of marvellous points inside a given triangle $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, there will be just one such point, but I may be mistaken. What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: I got a answer that it should be 325 but the method and answer  are uncertain

Comment: I am confused! Considering some point $P$, its distance to $AB$ will determine the height of any triangle with base being part of $AB$. Thus all 9 triangles produced from segments of $AB$ have to have the same base. Since those MUST constitute $1/3$ of the area of $\Delta ABC$, the distance from $P$ to $AB$ can be determined fully by this. Similar for the other two sides, which places $P$ in just one location, I should think.

Comment: But maybe I do not understand the setup, or maybe you could make it more clear and share your work so far :)

Comment: If first we select a point Which divides the area into l:m:n ratio if l+m+n= 27 then we have to devide that 3 triangles into the ratio so we have 27 small triangles

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. Thanks!

Comment: So the answer is $\binom{26}{2}$.

Comment: Is that the only way to find such points I want to confirm that

Comment: @ThishankaAlahakoon: It must be. The first side must have $1\leq l\leq 25$ parts. The second side must have $1\leq m\leq 26-l$ parts where it is 26 since the last side must have at least one part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "intersecting the sides or vertices of $\triangle ABC$, the three rays must be drawn through the vertices, otherwise a quadrilateral will be formed on the vertex. Then from the point $P$ there must be drawn $24$ rays to the sides of $\triangle ABC$. Let the areas of the triangles $\triangle PBC$, $\triangle PAC$, $\triangle PAB$ be in ratio $a:b:c$, respectively. Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

Then:
$$S_{\triangle PBC}=\frac{a}{27}S_{\triangle ABC}; \qquad 
S_{\triangle PAC}=\frac{b}{27}S_{\triangle ABC}; \qquad 
S_{\triangle PAB}=\frac{c}{27}S_{\triangle ABC}.$$

We will show that the point $P$ is unique for each ratio $a:b:c$. Note:
$$a+b+c=27 \Rightarrow c=27-a-b; \\
PF=\frac{2S_{\triangle PBC}}{BC}=\frac{2aS_{\triangle ABC}}{27}; \ \
PD=\frac{2S_{\triangle PAC}}{AC}=\frac{2bS_{\triangle ABC}}{27}; \\
PE=\frac{2S_{\triangle PAB}}{AB}=\frac{2cS_{\triangle ABC}}{27}=\frac{2(27-a-b)S_{\triangle ABC}}{27}.$$
For each set of $a,b,c$, the altitudes $PF, PD, PE$ are uniquely determined.

Now we want the areas of $\triangle PBC$, $\triangle PAC$, $\triangle PAB$ to be in the ratio $a:b:c$ such that:
$$a,b,c\in \mathbb{N^+};\\
1\le a,b,c\le 25; \\
a+b+c=27.$$
Then we can have $a,b,c$ small triangles.

Using stars and bars method we find:
$${27-1\choose 3-1}={26\choose 2}=325.$$

Answer (score 2):

As you insist the regions are all triangles, the $27$ rays must include
$PA$, $PB$ and $PC$. Then the triangles $PAB$, $PBC$ and $PAC$ must be
divided into $r$, $s$ and $t$ little triangles where $r$, $s$ and $t$
are positive numbers adding to $27$. I claim that for each triple
$(r,s,t)$ there is exactly one $P$ that works. To see this, the locus of
$P$ with area$(PAB)=(r/27)$ area$(ABC)$ is a line parallel to $AB$.
Likewise the locus of $P$ with area$(PBC)=(s/27)$ area$(ABC)$ is a
line parallel to $BC$. These do meet at a unique point $P$, and
then automatically area$(PCA)=(t/27)$ area$(ABC)$.

We now need to count the triples $(r,s,t)$. The map $(r,s,t)\to\{r,r+s\}$
bijects them to the two-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,26\}$ and there
are $\binom{26}2$ of these.

This answer is partly based on String's comments.

Comment: Here is an online GeoGebra-applet showing the [325 different situations](https://www.geogebra.org/m/VutAM5UC)